# How do I make a button work on 2 different conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that have below condition:

1. when the "Printing Form" button is clicked,the form will popup and prompt user to fill in the required details
2. when the "Complete"button in the table is click,the same form will be popup and prompt user to fill in the required details
   but the different is when the user click on "Printing Form" button,fill in the required details and click submit,the function submitdata() will be begin,and when the user click submit on"Complete" button,the function submitdata1() will begin as below

```
    // submiting data 
        function submitdata() {
          var $this      = $(this);
          var $div       = $this.parent("div");
          var $container = $this.parents(".msp__form_plf").find("table");
          var $slipdate  = $container.find("input[type='date']");
          var $isvalid   = $slipdate.next("span");
          var $article   = $container.find(".__articleno");
          var $daily     = $container.find("input[type='radio']:checked");
          var $form      = $container.find(".plf__material_list");
          var $ol        = $form.find(".material__list");
          var $inputs    = $ol.find("input[type='number']").filter(function() { return (this.value && this.value != 0); } );
          var $heat      = $form.find("input[type='checkbox']");

          var logtype    = $heat.is(":checked") ? "heat" : $plf_form_type.val();
          var idschedule = $article.val();
          var dailyshift = $daily.val();
          var slipdate   = $slipdate.val();
          var records    = [];

          var isvalid = $isvalid.hasClass("plf-invalid") || false;

          if($inputs.length Please Choose A Material");
              $article.val("").trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
          });
        }
```

and this is the function submitdata1:

```
    // submiting data 
        function submitdata1() {
          var $this      = $(this);
          var $div       = $this.parent("div");
          var $container = $this.parents(".msp__form_plf").find("table");
          var $slipdate  = $container.find("input[type='date']");
          var $isvalid   = $slipdate.next("span");
          var $article   = $container.find(".__articleno");
          var $daily     = $container.find("input[type='radio']:checked");
          var $form      = $container.find(".plf__material_list");
          var $ol        = $form.find(".material__list");
          var $inputs    = $ol.find("input[type='number']").filter(function() { return (this.value && this.value != 0); } );
          var $heat      = $form.find("input[type='checkbox']");

          var logtype    = $heat.is(":checked") ? "heat" : $plf_form_type.val();
          var idschedule = $article.val();
          var dailyshift = $daily.val();
          var slipdate   = $slipdate.val();
          var records    = [];

          var isvalid = $isvalid.hasClass("plf-invalid") || false;

          if($inputs.length Please Choose A Material");
              $article.val("").trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
          });
        }
```

So,my question is ,how can i make the submit button to work based "Printing Form" button or "Complete" button?

Thanks in advance.

This is for the "Printing Form" button in html template

data-href="msp__form_wrapper/p">Printing Form

and this is for the "Complete" button,it is in php

$row[11] =  onclick='open_wrappers();'>Complete";

Comment: `if($inputs.length Please Choose A Material");` huh? which language are you using?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `php`?

Comment: sorry for my mistake,i will attach the modify code here

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$('#buttonPrint').click(function(){
  $('#myForm').attr('action', 'printdata()');
  // Show Form
});


$('#buttonComplete').click(function(){
  $('#myForm').attr('action', 'submitdata()');
  //Show Form
});
```

Comment: how to use it as this is my submit button in tpl <pre><div class="__action_plf">
      <a class="f-r submit__form_btn">Submit</a>
    </div></pre>

Comment: this is what support to be<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46VQHVMeBTNN2FScG1wRC1QNFU/view?usp=sharing">my form</a>

Comment: I think code above is self explanatory.. Where you are having problem..?

Comment: my problem is i want to have one "submit" button in the form but have two different function?Is it possible to do this :<div class="__action_plf">
      <a class="f-r submit__form_btn">Submit</a>
    </div>

Comment: Ohh.. I got it.. you are confused with submit button. The Submit button of your form remain unchanged. You'll just change form action. I have updated code.

Comment: Apologise me for my stupidness,but i'm really didn't get you

Comment: ok.. you need to be online.. come at chat forum https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to enable me to chat in chat forum

Comment: got it.. can you post you html code of `buttons` (Complete and Print) and `form` ..?

Comment: Do i post it here?

Comment: this is for the "printing form" button<pre><a class='btn btn-small' data-href="msp__form_wrapper/p">Printing Form</a></pre>